# Accessing the state of a function at exit time (stop)

Tags: r

Let the following function:

```r
tmp <- function(x){
      y <- 10
      stop('foo')
    }
```

In reality, it's a function I don't have control of; I can't change its code.

How do I get to know the value of `y` as defined in the function when `stop` is invoked, programmatically?

Interactively, I can do the following:

```r
options(error = quote(dump.frames("testdump", FALSE)))
tmp()
v <- get("y", testdump[[1]]) 
options(error = NULL)
```

I do get an error but can still get to the value of `y` thanks to `dump.frames`.

I've been reading http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html but I must have missed a trick because I can't make that work programmatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following code **all at once** (so not line by line), it will give you what you desire

```
tmp <- function(x){
  y <- 10
  stop('foo')
}
x= 1
debug(tmp)
tmp(x)
n
n
v <<- y
n
```

Let me explain what happened. `debug(tmp)` makes R starts an interactive debug session as soon as `tmp(x)` is called.

This is just a hack in our case to get into the function environment. In the interactive situation, `n` will make the cursor go to the next line. We need to go two lines down before we get to the line where y is defined.

After `y = 10` is run in the function, we can assign y to our global environment. This is what the operator `<<-` does. It assigns the variable y in the function environment to the variable v in the global environment.

Then I choose to exit the interactive session by executing `stop("foo")`, but you could also do something else here to step out of the function environment, that is up to you.

If you want to see what is happening you could just execute this line by line too.

Comment: Thanks but I'd need to know exactly when `y` is defined and the calls to `stop` could be in multiple places in the original code. The value of `y` when `stop` is invoked is what I'm after.

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean.

However, you don't need to know exactly when `y` is defined. You just need to make sure that the cursor is after the definition of `y` and before `stop` when you call `v <<- y`. You could do this by a process of trial and error. This means that you could do `v <<- y` right before stop is executed and then you would get the value of `y` when `stop` is invoked. Does this help? If not, don't hesitate to add a new comment with the problem.

Comment: in my case, the actual function `tmp` is a black box and I'd like to use a solution that works for any function so I can't rely on the exact location of the definition of `y` and all its updates. I'm trying to use something like `tryCatch` or `withCallHandlers` but I haven't had any luck so far.